# Rmarkdown PDF in line citations not rendering correctly

Tags: emacs, markdown, pandoc

I am working with EMACS/Zotero/rmarkdown. Zotero is linked to EMACS with zotxt.

The in line citations are not following the .csl format correctly. For example, using the American Psychological Association 7th edition (apa.csl) format, in line citations should be in as follow:

```
(R Core Team, 2022)
```

But I am getting:

```
R Core Team (2022)
```

MRE is:

```
---
title: "literature review"
author: "Me"
date: "06/22/2022"
output: pdf_document
bibliography: references.json
csl: apa.csl
---

## Test text
This is just a test @rcoreteam2022. That citation should appear as 
"(R Core Team, 2022)", but it does not.

## References
```

Pdf screenshot

[image]

The pdf is rendered with:

```
render("mre.rmd", "pdf_document")
```

The .csl should be correct, I exported it out of Zotero and the Zotero preview gives the correct format.

Comment: How do you convert markdown to pdf. pandoc? If so, it's not related to emacs.

Comment: Yes, I use pandoc. Just trying to explain the framework that I am using. And you are correct, I get the same results in RStudio.

Comment: You can look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288699/pandoc-not-converting-latex-style-citations-correctly. If this doesn't solve your problem. I suggest you add your `pandoc` options like that question.

Answer (score 1):

After a bunch of searching, I figured it out. I found this blog post helpful:
https://plantarum.ca/2020/07/20/blogdown-citations/
Basically, my citation keys need to be in brackets, so instead of:

```
This is just a test @rcoreteam2022.
```

I need to use:

```
This is just a test [@rcoreteam2022].
```

And for multiple citations:

```
This is just a test [@rcoreteam2022; @Smith_2002].
```